# How do I remove the &nbsp; that seems to be automated in Magento

Tags: php, css, magento

Im working in Magento with adding Categories. For some reason if I add a category that is long, I get an unwanted result as seen below. It appears that after I save the categories in the backend, it adds `&nbsp;` to the code:

`<span>Research&nbsp;Reports&nbsp;On&nbsp;College&nbsp;Transitions</span>`

[image]

The result I am trying to get is this:

[image]

any clue how I can accomplish this?

Comment: `&nbsp;` is just an html entity for a space... I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: yes, but it also away to keep text from wrapping in code. Im trying to get the code to wrap if its long, but the generated `&nbsp;` is preventing that from happening. I work more with opencart, so Im not familiar with magento code, and so I'm not sure how to get my desired results.

Comment: you need to find the function that's generating the menu and get rid of the &nbsp from there. it's going to be tough, i've found it hard to navigate in Magento since its so large.

Comment: @Chad it's not just a space, it's a non-breakable space, i.e. it doesn't wrap (or adhere to natural line breaks).

Comment: I wonder if this is a custom template or something because I am having trouble finding the behavior you are talking about. Everywhere that my Magento store displays category names they do not have `&nbsp;` included.